# Correcting a grammar mistake

Tags: grammaticality

> "French is my first language in which I am very articulate"

My professor challenged us to this one.
It is indeed awkward, but I can’t spot the grammatical mistake. :/

Comment: It seems a bit much to call it a grammar mistake, but it's ambiguous exactly what you are saying. Is "in which I am very articulate" supposed to modify "French" or "first language"? You could say "French, in which I am very articulate, is my first language".

Comment: I agree with Stuart; the placement of the relative clause seems off. As it is, you are saying that French is the first language in which you are articulate, but I guess the aim of the sentence is to say that you are very articulate in French, as it is your first language.

Comment: You need a comma in there. Also, being articulate and being fluent are not the same.

Comment: "French, in which I am very articulate, is my first language" is totally grammatical but carries a hint of redundancy. I'd use "French is my first language, and I am very articulate in the language." (But it's not and I'm not.)